# ¿Cómo puedo realizar varias consultas en R con SQL?

Tags: r, datatables, sql, bucle-for

Tengo un conjunto de fechas y lo que quiero hacer es una consulta de una base de datos por cada fecha. Se resuelve facil con un for, pero bueno, que os voy a decir de los for, pues eso que se eterniza haciendo la consulta.

```
fechas <- data.table(c("20200101","20200201","20200301"))
colnames(fechas) <- "dias"

ndias <- length(fechas)
lista <- list()
for (i in 1:ndias) {
  lista[[i]] <- as.data.table(dbGetQuery(conexion,paste0("select nombre, edad, ",fechas$dias[i]," AS dia
                                                              from tabladatos
                                                              where inicio <=",fechas$dias[i])))

}
datos<- rbindlist(lista)
```

Al ser una conexión el código que pongo no lo vais a poder usar, pero creo que os haceis una idea, es como hacer 3 consultas uno para cada dia que hay en el data de fechas, se meten en una lista y luego se juntan todos.

No se si con alguna función de la familia Apply, yo lo he intentado pero soy incapaz.

Comment: Viendo tu código estas duplicando información, primer pides filas hasta el 1/1, luego hasta 1/2 por ultimo hasta el 1/3, no entiendo muy bien a que apuntas, por que divides en tres  lo que aparentemente podrías resolver en una única consulta

Comment: Lo que quiero con el código es que me saque la información para el día 20200101 y cree la variable dia que sea igual a 20200101. Luego saque la información para el dia 20200201 y cree la variable dia que sea igual a 20200201, y lo mismo para el tercer dia.
Pense en sacar toda la información de 1 vez y luego ir creando la variable día. El problema que tendria es que, por ejemplo, si para el dia 20200301 no hay información hay que usar la del 20200201 pero pegando la variable dia del 20200301 por lo que es más comodo con la consulta.

Answer (score 0):

Hola para resolver lo que mencionas puedes utilizar base R o una librería que se llama purrr que funciona mu similar apply o lapply de R el primero ejemplo lo mostrare con purrr

```
library(purrr)

infechas <- data.table(c("20200101","20200201","20200301"))
colnames(fechas) <- "dias"

ndias <- length(fechas)
lista <- list()

#Utilizando purrr
 datos<- map(infechas,function(x){ dbGetQuery(conexion,paste0("select nombre, edad, 
                                                       ",x[["dias"]]," AS dia
                                                          from tabladatos
                                               where inicio  <=",x[["dias"]]))) %>%
                                               reduce(rbind)
  #reduce ayuda a juntar toda la información de las diferentes litas
  # en un solo data frame o data.table si así lo deseas                                            

 #Ejercio utilizando lapply
 datos<- lapply(infechas,function(x){ dbGetQuery(conexion,paste0("select nombre, edad, 
                                                       ",x[["dias"]]," AS dia
                                                          from tabladatos
                                               where inicio  <=",x[["dias"]]))) %>%
                                               reduce(rbind)
```

Answer (score 0):

Antes que nada, existe la idea equivocada que las funciones de la familia `*apply` aportan una mejora en la performance a un ciclo `for`  explicito, pero lo cierto es que no, lo que aportan es más sencillez al código, lo que por otra parte es muy importante.

En primer lugar, mejoraría un poco el ciclo, iterando sobre las consultas ya construidas:

```
fechas <- c("20200101","20200201","20200301")
consultas <- paste0("select nombre, edad, '", fechas, "' AS dia  from tabladatos where inicio <= '", fechas, "'")
consultas

[1] "select nombre, edad, '20200101' AS dia  from tabladatos where inicio <= '20200101'"
[2] "select nombre, edad, '20200201' AS dia  from tabladatos where inicio <= '20200201'"
[3] "select nombre, edad, '20200301' AS dia  from tabladatos where inicio <= '20200301'"
```

Entonces podrías hacer:

```
for (consulta in consultas) {
  lista[[i]] <- as.data.table(dbGetQuery(conexion, consulta))
}
```

O bien algo así

```
lista <- lapply(consultas, function(consulta) as.data.table(dbGetQuery(conexion, consulta)))
```

Sino, otra posibilidad que podrías estudiar, en cuanto a performance, es hacer una única consulta a la base de datos y dividir los datos que ya tienes en memoria, la idea sería algo así:

```
fechas <- c("20200101","20200201","20200301")
ultima_fecha <- max(fechas)
consulta <- paste0("select nombre, edad, inicio from tabladatos where inicio <= '", ultima_fecha, "'")
datos <- dbGetQuery(conexion, consulta)

for (fecha in fechas) {
  lista[[i]] <- as.data.table(cbind(datos[datos$inicio <= fecha, ], dia=fecha))
}
```